# Looped Tasks Submitted Inside Try/Catch Blocks

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, try-catch, task

I have a background task "submitter" that handles one or more scheduled tasks:

```
...
While sdr.read()
    ...
    Dim oBackground As New Background
    Task.Run(Sub() CallByName(oBackground, sProcessKey, CallType.Method, iPQID))
End While
```

Before you ask, yes, the tasks are thread-safe.  :)

I want the submitter to end (go back to sleep) while the tasks operate; awaiting the next heartbeat, but I need to catch and handle exceptions in each thread.

The only way I've come up with to do this is to create a new task for each background job to be run and handle the exception there, but this seems inefficient:

Create new Task for each background job that then, submits the actual job and waits to see if an error happened and handles it:

```
Private Sub NewJob(sProcessKey, iPQID)
    Dim t As Task
    ....
    While sdr.read()
        ...
        Dim oBackground As New Background
        t = Task.Run(Sub() CallByName(oBackground, sProcessKey, CallType.Method, iPQID))
        Try
            t.Wait()
        Catch ex As AggregateException 
            For Each IEx As Exception In ex.InnerExceptions
                HandleBackgroundException(IEx, sProcessKey)
            Next
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

Isn't there a better way to do this??

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `t.Wait` use `await Task.Run(...)`

Comment: Thank you Fabio, I get your point - create an Async task and use Await, but any thoughts on my point of spawning a thread that spawns the worker thread in order to catch exceptions?

Comment: `Task.Run` returns `Task` which should be "awaited" if you want catch exceptions. You don't need to create another task only for exceptions. Of course if `CallByName` method call some asynchronous methods they should be awaited as well

Comment: Thanks again, Fabio, but maybe I wasn't clear. Using Await at this level (first code block) will STOP the submitter while the task runs - not allowing it to submit multiple tasks (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the answer to my own question.

Since each task is it's own thread, no additional thread submittal is needed.

The task is run directly and error handling happens within the task as shown above (but without Await'ing it). Thus:

```
Public Shared Sub MyTask()
    Try
        ... do some work here ...
    Catch ex As AggregateException
        For Each IEx As Exception In ex.InnerExceptions
            HandleBackgroundException(IEx, sProcessKey)
        Next
    End Try
End Sub
```

That's it!

I hope this helps someone else.